# Height percentage of submit button affects position of prior text input.

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<form action="add_chat_message/" method="post" id="add_chat_message">
   <input type="text" id="chat_message_text"><input type="submit" id="chat_message_submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input{ border: 1px solid black; }

#add_chat_message{
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#chat_message_text{
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 40%;
}

#chat_message_submit{
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F3hfD/74/ - In this example, the top of the text input does not touch the red border of the containing form. What confuses me though, is that this seems to be based on the height of the submit button. Changing the submit button's percentage from 100% to 40% fixes the issue (but of course I want the submit to take up the full height). What is the reason for this behaviour? I cannot see why a later element would affect the positioning of a prior one. In fact, leaving submit's percentage as 100% and changing the text's font size from 40% to 100% makes *submit* the one that is misaligned.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `vertical-align: top` on the input element.

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F3hfD/75/

Comment: All of them, i didn't know that, well that's cool. Guess i learnt something!

Comment: How come it was being weird before that though? Just CSS craziness?

Comment: Think so! That always happens to me too

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to add `display: flex` to the parent `div` see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/F3hfD/76/

```
#add_chat_message{
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: flex;
}
```